# Getting the value on a php loop via javascript / ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, return-value

I have loaded data in a table via ajax just like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    });
```

> now i have a button 'edit' for each row, (the code for this is at the php file for example like:

```
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["BatchCode"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["StudentNo"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["Lname"].' '.$row["Fname"].'</td>';    
        echo '<td>'.$row["Department"].'</td>';             
        echo '<td>'.'<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="edit" value="'.$id.'">Edit</button>'.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

> I am working with 2 pages, the index.php and fetch.php, wherein the data from fetch.php will be loaded on index.php via ajax. 
>   Now my problem is, i cant get the value/id of a specific row that i want to edit. I don't know what else to do, any idea? Tyia! :)) Sorry if i can't explain it well

[image]

Comment: Did you miss the TR?

Comment: @epascarello nope..

Comment: So you are posting the form to the next page and you are not getting the value of the submit button you pressed?

Comment: @epascarello yes, the button is on php loop.

Comment: @epascarello i edited and posted a photo to help explaining it well ...

Comment: I understand how it renders, I just do not know what your issue is. Your form submission should have the button name with the value in it wither in the querystring or post body.

Comment: @epascarello yes it has, i tried to print the value in alert box, but i am getting the first value on the loop and not the correct value.

Comment: Show how you tried to read the value, unclear how you are not getting the right value.

Comment: @epascarello  i tried this
<button type="button" onclick="fl(this)" class="btn btn-success" name="edit" value="'.$id.'">Edit</button>

function fl(objButton){  
    alert(objButton.value);
}

Comment: That looks correct to me

Comment: @epascarello oh, it worked! i got the right value (i didnt know how it happened) now my problem is, how will i pass it on a modal (._.) *the modal is on index.php* tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting the $id variable?

I can't see it, so try $_ROW['id'] in the value instead of $id

Hope it helps